# keystoneJs "not authorized for query on keystone.app_updates"

Tags: mongodb, keystone

I trying to run a keystoneJs project on server, but it just down.I created a user on mongodb with user:pwd, And added the config into the `.env` file of keystone like doc said:

`MONGO_URI=mongodb://keystone:keystone@localhost:27017/keystone`

It connected success with the mongo cli.

```
> use keystone
switched to db keystone
>  db.auth({user:"keystone",pwd:"keystone"})
1
----------------------------------------------
> show dbs
admin     0.000GB
keystone  0.000GB
local     0.000GB
log4net   0.143GB
```

But the keystone always show the err below.

```
------------------------------------------------
An error occurred applying updates, bailing on Keystone init.

Error details:
MongoError: not authorized for query on keystone.app_updates
```

I have run a keystone project success at local with a default mongodb.
How do I config the keystone to a mongodb with auth? Can anybody show me the way?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that your keystone app is not picking up the .env file.

An alternative is to pass the URI to set the keystone mongo option before you initialise keystone.

`keystone.set("mongo","mongodb://keystone:keystone@localhost:27017/keystone")`

When I do this I set the password with a commandline arg so when i run the server it looks like:
`node keystone.js password`

And when I set the mongo uri it looks like:

```
password = process.argv[2]
keystone.set("mongo","mongodb://keystone:"+password"+@localhost:27017/keystone")
```

Just so I don't have a password sitting in plaintext in a file.